# Using ruby and mongo mapper without ruby on rails - best practices

Tags: ruby, mongomapper

How do I use Mongo Mapper and Ruby without having to create a rails project? I simply would like a ruby script to run and save data in a mongo database.

I can put the following code at the top of every class I use:

MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new('localhost')
MongoMapper.database = 'fakedb'

But what is the best practice? Do I create one file with the database connection configuration and then require it in each class? How do I do this?

Comment: are you sure you actually need Mongo Mapper?

Comment: I'm using Mongo Mapper to simplify my code's readability and keep me from having to interact with the structure of documents directly in my queries. Is there a better way to achieve this goal w/o Mongo Mapper?

Comment: sorry, you mentioned just saving, not querying

Answer (score 1):

in an object oriented way, i would wrap it into some helper class, maybe even a singleton.

i did some examples on mongodb and the different wrappers with sinatra. have a look at the code here: https://github.com/phoet/mongodb_examples/blob/master/lib/mongo_mapper_example.rb